# Painted color different to selected color

Tags: texture-painting

I'm just learning Blender and I've hit a wall with painting at the moment. The color which I select with the color picker isn't what shows up when used. Both with the fill tool as well as the brush. I've created a completely new scene and this still happens so can't be the scene. I've also tried deleting the brush and creating a new brush. Any help would be appreciated!

As you can see in the image I had an orange color selected but it painted yellow.

[image]

Comment: In what preview are you? What shading is used?

Comment: This is just the image painting window, there wouldn't be different shading modes would there? I'd assume it should be more like photoshop. 

But if I view the object in viewport shading it has the same issue.

Comment: my bad. Sorry didn't notice you are in image editor

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out since I had an aces colour space config on my PC which I used for Maya, Blender was picking this up and set it as my default colour space but the colour wheels don't change.
I just removed that and all is now as I would expect!